# Setting With Enlargement in daru

Tags: ruby, daru

There is some way to Setting With Enlargement in [daru](https://rubygems.org/gems/daru)? Something similar to [pandas with loc](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#setting-with-enlargement).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can.

For `Daru::Vector` objects use the `#push` method like so:

```
require 'daru'
v = Daru::Vector.new([1,2,3], index: [:a,:b,:c])
v.push(23, :r)
v
#=> 
#<Daru::Vector:74005360 @name = nil @size = 4 >
#    nil
#  a   1
#  b   2
#  c   3
#  r  23
```

For setting a new vector in `Daru::DataFrame`, call the `#[]=` method with your new name inside the `[]`. You can either assign a `Daru::Vector` or an `Array`.

If you assign `Daru::Vector`, the data will be aligned so that the indexes of the DataFrame and Vector match.

For example,

```
require 'daru'
df = Daru::DataFrame.new({a: [1,2,3], b: [5,6,7]})
df[:r] = [11,22,33]
df
# => 
#<Daru::DataFrame:73956870 @name = c8a65ffe-217d-43bb-b6f8-50d2530ec053     @size = 3>
#                    a          b          r 
#         0          1          5         11 
#         1          2          6         22 
#         2          3          7         33
```

You assign a row with the `DataFrame#row[]=` method. For example, using the previous dataframe `df`:

```
df.row[:a] = [23,35,2]
df
 #=> 
 #<Daru::DataFrame:73956870 @name = c8a65ffe-217d-43bb-b6f8-50d2530ec053  @size = 4>
 #                    a          b          r 
 #         0          1          5         11 
 #         1          2          6         22 
 #         2          3          7         33 
 #         a         23         35          2
```

Assigning a `Daru::Vector` will align according to the names of the vectors of the `Daru::DataFrame`.

You can see further details in [these notebooks](https://github.com/v0dro/daru#notebooks-on-most-use-cases).

Hope this answers your question.